# How to Fix Vi Editor?

Tags: command-line, bash, gcc, c, vi

A couple of days back, I was trying undergoing a tutorial from [KernelNewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and as it asked, I did made some changes to vi editor. But, it seems that I have messed up something. I am unable to find that tutorial back again and thus, unable to fix the editor. When now I am typing the command:

```
 $ vi openapp.c
```

instead, of creating and opening the  file, I get the message below:

```
"indent" [New File]
Error detected while processing /home/doherty/.vimrc:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: S
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And it creates a file named 'indent'.Also, its not compiling with the command

```
 $ gcc indent
```

Thanks in advance. Also, I did made some changes to the default editor.

`.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on syn on se title set tabstop=8 set softtabstop=8 set shiftwidth=8 set noexpandtab
```

Comment: As a quick fix, I imagine `mv /home/doherty/.vimrc /home/doherty/.vimrc.BACKUP` would work (I presume `vi` will work without a user config). That at least should give you a working editor until the problem is tracked down. Incidentally, could you add the relevant parts of your `.vimrc` to your question?  At least the first few lines (since line 2 seems to be problematic).

Comment: Here's what I see in $vi .vimrc 
`filetype plugin indent on
syn on se title
set tabstop=8
set softtabstop=8
set shiftwidth=8
set noexpandtab`

Comment: @RedFedora, you've altered the contents of the OP's .vimrc and I'm not sure why? My assumption is it's easier to fix if we can see what it _is_, rather than what it maybe should be. (I would edit it back, but <6 chars so SE won't let me)

Comment: Thanks, @David-Foerster - next time I'll do that (I've edited the relevant line now, but left genuine spelling corrections in place).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this file that is parsed everytime you start vim: /home/doherty/.vimrc -- You can post it as a comment to this and we can see if there is an error in it that can be fixed as well.

Comment: Would I have to use:?
$ rm *.vimrc

Comment: You could do 'rm /home/doherty/.vimrc' to get only that file

Comment: Was that an unnecessary file?

Comment: @Doherty it contains things that vi runs on startup. If you make mistakes in it vi may not start up at all.

Comment: `.vimrc` is Vim's user config. It's not necessary, but any modifications to Vim's usual behaviour that you wanted - you'd add them to `.vimrc`. If you can live without the changes, then removing the file is fine (always best to simply `mv` it, however, rather than `rm` it). It's "backed up" here, so you can always recover it later (when you find that elusive tutorial!)

Comment: Oops. I already `rm`ed it.  I hope I can later create it by `$ vi .vimrc` when needed.

Comment: You can - I added it to your question.  A quick-and-dirty way to recreate your `.vimrc` would be: `echo "filetype plugin indent on syn on se title set tabstop=8 set softtabstop=8 set shiftwidth=8 set noexpandtab" >> .vimrc` (that'll _append_, just in case in the meantime you've added to `.vimrc` and forgotten!)